# JQuery UI Dialog loses pre-loaded textarea values

Tags: forms, jquery-ui

When using jQuery UI Dialog, values loaded into form textarea fields that are part of the dialog are not displayed.

I am attempting to use a jQuery dialog to pop up a CRUD form. In the case of update (edit), the form fields are loaded with the values from the item being "edited."

When I open the dialog (if key == "edit"), the "name" field is displayed but the description textarea is not.

Viewing the HTML tab under Firebug, the text value of the textarea (that between the textarea and /textarea) is correctly set, but that value does not display in the resultant dialog:

```
<form id="CRUDform">
<fieldset>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" class="text ui-wiget-content ui-corner-all" type="text" style="display:block" value="[SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS]" name="name">
<label for="description">Description</label>
<textarea id="description" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:block" name="description">Description of Nothing</textarea>
<!-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I've found some references to issues with form fields related to dialogs being appending to the body of the document rather than the form, but that does not seem relevant to this case.

Platform: Windows 7 Professional
Browser: Firefox 24.0
Firebug: 1.12.3
jQuery: 1.9.1
jQuery UI: 1.10.3

Here is the test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.contextMenu.css">
<style>
.dialog
{
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".dialog").hide();

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.myContext' ,
        build: function ( trigger , thrown )
        {
            return (
            {
                autoHide: true ,
                callback: function ( key , menuOptions )
                {
                    var name = $(this).data("label");
                    var message = "menu action [" + key + "] on [" + name + "]";

                    window.console && console.log(message) || alert(message);

                    if (key == "new")
                    {
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            title: "Adding Child of " + name + " Class",
                            modal: true ,
                            buttons:
                            {
                                "Create" : function ()
                                {
                                    var name = $("#name").val();
                                    var description = $("#description").val();

                                    alert("Adding name [" + name + "] description [" + description + "]");

                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                                "Cancel" : function ()
                                {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function ()
                            {
                                $("#name").val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                                $("#description").val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (key == "edit")
                    {
                        var name = $(this).data("label");
                        var description = $(this).data("description");

                        console.log("editing name [", name , "] description [", description , "]");

                        $("#name").val(name);
                        $("#description").text(description);

                        console.log("name set to [" ,
                            $("#name").val() , "] description set to [",
                            $("#description").text() , "]");

                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            modal: true ,
                            title: "Editing " + name ,
                            buttons:
                            {
                                "Save" : function ()
                                {
                                    var name = $("#name").val();
                                    var description = $("#description").val();

                                    alert("Saving name [" + name + "] description [" + description + "]");

                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                                "Cancel" : function ()
                                {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function ()
                            {
                                $("#name").val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                                $("#description").val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                items:
                {
                    "new" : { name: "New", icon: "new" } ,
                    "edit" : { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" } ,
                    "delete" : { name: "Delete" , icon: "delete" }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
<body>
<title>jQuery Dialog Test</title>
</head>
<h1>jQuery Dialog Test</h1>
<div id="list" class="list">
<ul>
<li class="myContext" data-description="Description of Something" data-label="Something">Something</li>
<li class="myContext" data-description="Description of Something Else" data-label="Something Else">Something Else</li>
<li class="myContext" data-description="Description of Nothing" data-label="Nothing">Nothing</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog" title="Do Something">
    <h1>Doing Something</h1>
    <form id="CRUDform">
    <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="[SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS]" style="display:block" class="text ui-wiget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" style="display:block" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">[SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS]</textarea>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried isolating the issue? For example, removing the context menu plugin you appear to be using? Also, your opening body tag needs to come after the title and head elements.

Comment: j08691 - yes, I have a version that only has the dialog box opening whenever I click a list item, and it behaves the same way. However, there seems to be some issue related to persistence. More to follow.

Comment: At least part of the problem appears to be how I was setting and/or clearing the form fields. In other browsers and FF w/o FB, works as expected the first time but not afterwards.  In FF w/ FB, does not work even the first time. I am trying to establish a pattern of behavior with Firebug (FB) enabled.