# Jquery UI Dialog - textarea does not display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I am having an issue very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434131/jquery-ui-dialog-loses-pre-loaded-textarea-values).

However there has been no answer to that issue, and no activity in two months. So after much google searching without any luckI am posting here to see if anyone has any ideas.

Essentially, the text placed in between the textarea tags does not display in a jquery ui dialog.  This is true even when the html is hard coded. Upon inspection in chrome or firebug, the correct text shows up in the HTML, but it is not rendered.

Note: This is being done in a CodeIgniter Framework, so the JS is making a call to a controller to grab data from a model and load it to a view

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="popup-scroll"></div>
```

The JS like this:

```
$popupScroll = $('#popup-scroll');

window.editNotes = function (adminId) {

$popupScroll.html('<div id="!user-series-notes" data-source="/sepanel/students/seriesNotes/' + adminId + '"></div>').dialog({
  title: 'Edit User Series Notes',
  width: 565,
  height: 450,
  buttons: {
    Save: function () { saveNotes(adminId); },
    Cancel: _S.ui.closeDialog
  }
});

refreshNotes();
$(document).on('change', '#passed-series', function () {
  _S.ui.toggle($('#final-score'), $('#passed-series').is(':checked'));
});

};

function refreshNotes() {

var oldText = $('textarea[name=notes]').val();

_S.refresh('user-series-notes', function () {
  $('textarea[name=notes]').val(oldText);
  $('#exam-date').datepicker();
  $('#series-score').spinner({ min: 0 });
});

}
```

And the View like this:

```
    <form id="notes-form">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $admin->user_id; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="series_id" value="<?php echo $admin->series_id; ?>">
      <label class="admin-label">Notes:</label><textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo $admin->notes; ?></textarea>
    </form>
```

If anyone wants to see the Controller or Model I can post those too.

Comment: The best thing you could do to get this answered would be to reproduce the problem in isolation on JSFiddle or CodePen. A very simple attempt to reproduce the general description of the problem (ie, put a textarea inside a jQuery UI dialog) [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/CBagS/), so the problem must be related to something else in your code.

Comment: @Nate trying to isolate it lead me to the problem thank you.

Comment: Such is often the way of things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the refreshNotes() function.  Removing the var oldText and the line where it was passed as value to the textarea solved the issue.